# No Images in react native release bundle for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I've looked high and low at solutions to this problem, but none of them have worked.

on iOS, I'm making a release bundle with `react-native bundle --dev false --assets-dest ./ios/Bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ./ios/Bundle/main.jsbundle`

Afterwards, I'm adding the Bundle directory which includes the assets directory and the main.jsbundle to my project in XCode.

Then I change the Run scheme to work on the Release configuration, and run the project on a physical device.

React Native finds the bundle, but none of the static assets show up.

I'm on React Native 0.48

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else has a similar problem and needs some ideas where to look..

Check your xcode build logs and to see where your bundle is being created
probably something like

`/Users/johnsmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-asde14dwefda878/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app`

Inspect and make sure that `main.jsbundle` and `assets/` are both at the top level.
If they're not then check your arguments to the bundle command (called by the `bundle react native code and images` build phase by the `react-native-xcode.sh` command) the defaults should be fine. you can also use `set -x` to print out more info about what's being called, or click `show environment variables in build log`

Assuming that everything is in the correct location...then try looking where the code is really looking for the image

```
import background from "../../assets/background.png"
alert(Image.resolveAssetSource(background).uri);
```

Inspect in file explorer and see if you can find the file. The folder my code was looking in was this:

```
/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/718SDF9995-1123D6-46A8-93DD-830963FC4372/data/Containers/Data/Application/25C8SG9C-2CSA-4891-BDFD-B6B37A3B4022/Library/Application Support/.expo-internal/
```

In my case I had ejected from expo and the file was there under a hash but the code was looking for it as `../assets/background.png` It was using expo-asset to resolve the file in release (not metro as in debug), the fix was to add

```
../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-ios.sh
```

to the end of the `Bundle React Native code and images` build phase and to add
import 'expo-updates'
to the top of my `App.tsx` file

Another idea would be to add an external image and see if it can load that.

```
source={{uri:'https://......../...png'}}
```

There's also the problem with Ios14 images that can be fixed by updating react-native or using `npx react-native-fix-image` but that would also affect dev builds